# c# dataGridView current cell in some function

Tags: c#, datagridview

Hello and sorry for my English.

```
dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
```

This function has parameter DataGridViewCellEventArgs e, with whose help i can find out clicked cell:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString()
```

But im writing function for Word Export:

```
private void WordExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Which work when i click on button. In this function i need to know current cell, same as in 
dataGridView1_CellClick function - dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString()

How can i get it?

Comment: What's the `current` cell in this case?

Comment: Try `gridView.CurrentCell` property or `gridView.SelectedCells` for multiselect mode. If i got you right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataGridView` has property `CurrentCell` which is a reference to currently selected cell (can be null!). So to use it in your word export event do following:

```
private void WordExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell == null) //no cell is selected.
    {
         return;
    }

    var value = dataGridVIew1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
    //or if you always want a value from cell in first column
    var value = dataGridVIew1.CurrentCell.OwningRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString()    
}
```

hope that helps you out. Good luck :)